# AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'create_rectangle'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Trying to make a flappy bird clone and am having troubles with spawning in the object that will be the bird. I have tried to fix it by myself but I cannot think of why it isn't working. Tried to find if there was any fix online and I came up empty. I don't understand what the issue is and why it isn't spawning. I can't think of how to fix it. my code is here.

```
import tkinter


class Menu:

    _BUTTON_HEIGHT = 2
    _BUTTON_WIDTH = 10
    _PLAY_BUTTON = "Start"
    _EXIT_BUTTON = "Exit"

    def __init__(self):
        """"""
        self.canvas = tkinter.Tk()
        self.play_button = None
        self.exit_button = None
        self.starting_game_new = None

    def canvas_create(self):
        """Creates a window for the frame to be displayed"""
        self.canvas.geometry("500x700")

    def menu_buttons(self):
        """"""
        self.play_button = tkinter.Button(self.canvas,
                                          command=self.start_game,
                                          text=Menu._PLAY_BUTTON,
                                          width=Menu._BUTTON_WIDTH,
                                          height=Menu._BUTTON_HEIGHT)
        self.play_button.pack()

        self.exit_button = tkinter.Button(self.canvas,
                                          command=self.exit_game,
                                          text=Menu._EXIT_BUTTON,
                                          width=Menu._BUTTON_WIDTH,
                                          height=Menu._BUTTON_HEIGHT)
        self.exit_button.pack()

    def start_game(self):
        self.play_button.pack_forget()
        self.exit_button.pack_forget()
        self.starting_game_new = GameFrame(canvas=self.canvas)
        self.starting_game_new.create_frame()
        self.starting_game_new.create_bird()

    def exit_game(self):
        self.canvas.destroy()


class GameFrame:

    _FRAME_HEIGHT = 700
    _FRAME_WIDTH = 500
    _FRAME_COLOUR = "dodger blue"
    _X_BIRD = 200
    _X_BIRD_2 = 250
    _Y_BIRD = 150
    _Y_BIRD_2 = 200
    _BIRD_COLOUR = "gold2"

    def __init__(self, canvas):
        """"""
        self.game_frame = None
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.bird = None

    def create_frame(self):
        """Creates the game canvas and background"""
        self.game_frame = tkinter.Canvas(self.canvas,
                                         width=GameFrame._FRAME_WIDTH,
                                         height=GameFrame._FRAME_HEIGHT,
                                         background=GameFrame._FRAME_COLOUR)
        self.game_frame.pack()

    def create_bird(self):
        self.bird = self.canvas.create_rectangle(GameFrame._X_BIRD,
                                                 GameFrame._Y_BIRD,
                                                 GameFrame._X_BIRD_2,
                                                 GameFrame._Y_BIRD_2,
                                                 fill=GameFrame._BIRD_COLOUR)


def main():
    start = Menu()
    start.canvas_create()
    start.menu_buttons()
    start.canvas.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Error code here:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "(file)**init**.py", line 1883, in call return self.func(*args) File "", line 50, in start_game self.starting_game_new.create_bird() File "D:/Downloads/flappybirdgame-main/aewf.py", line 82, in create_bird self.bird = self.canvas.create_rectangle(GameFrame._X_BIRD, File "", line 2345, in getattr return getattr(self.tk, attr) AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'create_rectangle'

Comment: Post the entire error code please.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "(file)__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "", line 50, in start_game
    self.starting_game_new.create_bird()
  File "D:/Downloads/flappybirdgame-main/aewf.py", line 82, in create_bird
    self.bird = self.canvas.create_rectangle(GameFrame._X_BIRD,
  File "", line 2345, in __getattr__
    return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'create_rectangle'

Comment: The error is because you said `self.canvas = tkinter.Tk()` and your passing on that as your canvas. Why? You need to pass a canvas on, not a `Tk()` window.

Answer (score 0):

The method `create_rectangle` is a method on your canvas. Your variable `self.canvas` is not a canvas, it's the root window.

You need to create a tkinter `Canvas` widget in order to draw a rectangle. It looks like you're doing so in this line:

```
self.game_frame = tkinter.Canvas(self.canvas, ...)
```

So, you need to call `create_rectangle` on this widget instead of `self.canvas`:

```
self.bird = self.game_frame.create_rectangle(...)
```